# Logging time taken by Sunspot and solr in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, solr, sunspot

When a GET request is made, the time taken by Sunspot and solr is displayed

```
Started GET "/collections/AA1/items/001" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 15:11:00 +1100
...
Completed 200 OK in 220.1ms (Views: 139.9ms | ActiveRecord: 59.4ms | Solr: 583.7ms)
```

However, when a PUT request is made, the time taken by Sunspot and solr is displayed in the various sub-lines, but not at the end

```
Started PUT "/collections/AA1/items/001" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 15:10:59 +1100
...
  SOLR Request (456.0ms) ...
...
  SOLR Request (127.8ms) ...
...
Completed 302 Found in 1192.9ms (ActiveRecord: 211.4ms)
```

This is a problem because when logging happens in production, the sub-lines aren't displayed.

How can I get it to list time by Sunspot and Solr in the final line, like

```
Completed 302 Found in 1192.9ms (ActiveRecord: 211.4ms | Solr: 123.4 ms)
```

?